# How to Count Data from Another Function

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a trouble from my controller. When i want to count the array from another function in controller is get a error cannot to count

I get this error

> Call to a member function get() on array

This my controller :

```
Function A
public function detailFees(){
$dataArray = array(
    'datapayment' => $datapayment,
    'countafter' => $countafter,
    'countbefore' => $countbefore
  );
}

Function B
public function data(){
$data = count($this->detailFees($market)->get(datapayment))
}
```

I want to count just array data in datapayment with result in number

Thanks for help!

Comment: You're missing a `return` in `detailFees()`. Also that function doesn't take an argument. Also it certainly doesn't/won't return an object on which to call `get()`.

Comment: Do you mean counting the items in the array which is 3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, there are few ways to achieve your goal. The minimum cost is just returning $dataArray in function A

```
public function detailFees( $market ){
    // .... your other codes
    $dataArray = array(
        'datapayment' => $datapayment,
        'countafter'  => $countafter,
        'countbefore' => $countbefore
    );
    return $dataArray; // add this line
}
```

and then consume the returned array from function A to function B:

```
public function data(){
    $data = count($this->detailFees($market)['datapayment']); // change this line
}
```

simple without many changes.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use get() on an array because it is not a valid operation, and your detailFees() method does not accept any arguments because you did not define a parameter in the method.

To count the array, you can do this:

```
// Function B
public function data() {
    $dataArray = $this->detailFees();
    $datapayment = $dataArray['datapayment'];
    $dataCount = count($datapayment);


    return $dataCount;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Inorder to make use of the [get()](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/collections#method-get) method, convert the array as a [collection](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/collections) using the [collect()](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/collections#method-collect) helper method.

Function A:

```
public function detailFees($key)
{
    $dataArray = collect([
        'datapayment' => $datapayment,
        'countafter'  => $countafter,
        'countbefore' => $countbefore,
    ]);

    $item = $dataArray->get($key);

    if (
        is_null($item)
        || ! is_array($item)
    ) {
        return 0;
    }

    return count($item);
}
```

Function B:

```
public function data()
{
    $data = $this->detailFees('datapayment');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Try this

```
public function detailFees(){
$dataArray = array(
    'datapayment' => $datapayment,
    'countafter' => $countafter,
    'countbefore' => $countbefore
  );
  return $dataArray;
}


public function data(){
  $data = is_array($this->detailFees()['datapayment'])?count($this->detailFees()['datapayment']):0;
  return $data;
}
```